# How do I open the new dreamy content in Candy Crush?

Tags: candy-crush-saga

After level 50 I tried opening the next episode but there was no option like play quest and even when I tried to ask friends there's no reply

Comment: You're much more likely to get help if you use the appropriate tags

Comment: Steam... candy crush?